# How can I access memory-mapped GPIO registers with golang on Windows?

Tags: windows, go, gpio, memory-mapping, memory-mapped-io

I am working with a piece of harware, that addresses LEDs through GPIOs accessible only through memory-mapped IO (mmio registers).
On Linux, I managed to set the values pretty simple, by opening the documented address through `/dev/mem`:

```
var err error
mem, err = os.OpenFile("/dev/mem", os.O_RDWR|os.O_SYNC, 0644)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("could not initialize GPIO memory mapping")
}
_, err := mem.WriteAt(colorMap[ledColor], gpioPadBar + ledMap[pow])
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

This works pretty well on linux, but as there is no `/dev/mem` available on Windows to open, I am currently stuck on approaching the same results.

As I could not find anything on the internet (it does not help that MMIO is always pointing to File-MMIO in Windows context and the Windows-API bindings are only little documented), I tried to access the memory area directly:

```
func mmioWrite(offset int64, val byte) {
    *((*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(gpioPadBar + offset)))) = val
}
...
mmioWrite(colorMap[ledColor], ledMap[pow])
```

I executed it as administrator (as I am clearly requesting a kernel-managed resource), but it crashed [showing this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5qyS.png).

The "error address" (0xD0C506A0) is the correctly calculated MMIO GPIO address I wanted to access.

My questions are:

- Is there a low-level possibility to get MMIO-Register access on Windows?
- If not: Is there a Windows API to perform this task?

Thank you very much,
Mathias

Comment: Even on Linux it highly not recommended what you have done. On Windows though I can suggest to use Net IoT for the purpose. Not sure about golang.